# Map the first element of each array of an array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
myData = [
          ["name1", 34.1, 43.1, 55.2],
          ["name2", 5.3, 23.6, 40.9],
          ["name3", 43.5, 77.8, 22.4]
         ];
```

I want to get an array containing only the first element of each array like this: `["name1", "name2", "name3"]`.

I tried to do it like this but doesn't work:

```
var arrayTitle = myData.map(function(x) {
    return [myData[x][0]];
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `x` is an element of the array and not an index. And don't wrap the return value in an array `[]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could return just the first elementn of `x`, an element of the outer array.

```js
var myData = [["name1", 34.1, 43.1, 55.2], ["name2", 5.3, 23.6, 40.9], ["name3", 43.5, 77.8, 22.4]],
    arrayTitle = myData.map(function(x) {
        return x[0];
    });

console.log(arrayTitle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` itself is an array. So you need not to touch myData again inside.

```
var arrayTitle = myData.map(function(x) {
    return x[0];
});
```

or with a traditional loop

```js
myData = [
          ["name1", 34.1, 43.1, 55.2],
          ["name2", 5.3, 23.6, 40.9],
          ["name3", 43.5, 77.8, 22.4]
         ];


var arrayTitle = [];

for(var k in myData)
 arrayTitle.push(myData[k][0]);
 
 console.log(arrayTitle);
```

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects

Comment: for...in... will return the index of the array.  It returns the key for objects.

Answer (score 1):

With your actual code `return [myData[x][0]]`, you are returning `undefined`, because `x`  is the iterated item, so it's an `array` and not an index.

And using the wrapping `[]` is useless here, it's a destructing syntax, we don't need it here.

You should only return `item[0]` in each iteration:

```
var res = myData.map(function(arr) {
  return arr[0];
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
myData = [
  ["name1", 34.1, 43.1, 55.2],
  ["name2", 5.3, 23.6, 40.9],
  ["name3", 43.5, 77.8, 22.4]
];


var res = myData.map(function(arr) {
  return [arr[x][0]];
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the shortest answer:

`var res = myData.map(a => a[0])`