# Use Lodash to get first element of each array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

This question as a JS-only answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415245/map-the-first-element-of-each-array-of-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript). But simply because I'd like to become more proficient with Lodash, I'm looking for the Lodash solution.

Let's say I have an array that looks like:

`[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [h, i, j]]`

I'd like to get the first element of each array as its own array:

`[a, d, h]`

What is the most efficient way to do this with Lodash? Thanks.

Comment: `let result = arr.map(a => a[0])`

Comment: No need for lodash in this case

Comment: Lodash version: `let result = _.map(arr, a => a[0]);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) with [`_.head`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#head) for the first element.

```js
var data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j']],
    result = _.map(data, _.head);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or just the key.

```js
var data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j']],
    result = _.map(data, 0);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lol why do they have a method to get the first element of an array?

Comment: maybe for headers of tables?

Comment: Head is very useful! It comes from functional languages like lisp, scheme... you can usually add an argument to tell how many of the first elements you want, very basic but useful filtering. Also it’s Used in R, Python with data structures sushi as data frames.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use lodash:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const arr1 = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [h, i, j]]
arr2 = _.map(arr1, e => e[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can do this with `_.first`, [`_.head`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#head) (`_.first` is just an alias of `_.head`) and direct `path` while `mapping` through the array:

```js
const data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]

console.log(_.map(data, _.first))
console.log(_.map(data, _.head))
console.log(_.map(data, 0)) // direct path
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you however have to use `lodash` just for this then simply use either **ES6** or **ES5**:

```js
const data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]

console.log(data.map(x => x[0]))
console.log(data.map(function(x){ return x[0] }))
```

The performance and actual code is the same practically.

Answer (score 0):

[https://lodash.com/docs/#filter](https://lodash.com/docs/)

Use the docs, look for some each function.

```
let arr = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [h, i, j]]
let newArray = _.filter(arr, function(subArray){
   return subArray[0] // first element of each subArray
})
console.log(newArray)
```

This should do it, but I don't understand why you wanna use lodash when pretty much the same filter function exists in vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`_.matchesProperty`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#matchesProperty) iteratee shorthand, which many lodash methods support.

```js
const data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j']];

const result = _.map(data, '[0]');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```